# PhoneGap Facebook Plugin compilation error in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, facebook, cordova

on my attempt to build a PhoneGap-based iOS app, I stumbled upon this problem.  The app is using [facebook connect plugin](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect) provided by phonegap team.  I followed the instructions on the README, and encountered this compilation error on Xcode:

/../facebook-ios-sdk/src/FBRequest.m:183: error: 'SBJSON' undeclared (first use in this function)
/../facebook-ios-sdk/src/FBRequest.m:183: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/../facebook-ios-sdk/src/FBRequest.m:183: error: for each function it appears in.)
/../facebook-ios-sdk/src/FBRequest.m:183: error: 'jsonParser' undeclared (first use in this function)

I am new to phonegap and Xcode/iOS development, so would appreciate any help on resolving this error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem, turned out I was using updated (but not released) forked phonegap library, which the SBJSON class has been renamed to PG_SBJSON.  Manually changed the SBJSON class to PG_SBJSON resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded to PhoneGap 1.1.0 .. you need to degrade to PhoneGap
1.0.0 since the new version does not work correctly with the Facebook
Plugin.